# How to add a custom field to an object before GSON parsing

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have a situation when the server returns a list of players in the team, but the player object doesn't contain the team id and I need to pass it by hand, or walk a looper after receiving

I'm using **Retrofit 2.1** and **Gson 2.7**

I have some Gson model

```
public class SomeClass {

    @SerializedName("fieldFromJSON")
    private String mFieldFromJSON;
    private String mCustomField; //<= This field is not in response

    //... Empty constructor, getters and setters
}
```

and the Retrofit interface

```
@GET("some/url")
Call<List<SomeClass>> getData(
        String customField //<= This I must put to all classes in customField
);
```

gives this response

```
[
    {
        "fieldFromJSON":"something"
    }
    //, {...}, ...
]
```

Is it possible to create `List` of `SomeClass` and put a customField to all the `SomeClass` classes by using Retrofit and Gson?

Comment: You are asking how to "inject" a java member variable at runtime? Without reflection, I doubt that is possible, and certainly out of scope of either Gson, Android, or Retrofit. Or are you wanting to know when the loop over the list and do `SomeClass.setCustomField(customField)`?

Comment: Hmm, I have a situation when the server returns a list of players in the team, but the player object doesn't contain the team id and I need to pass it by hand, or walk a looper after receiving

Comment: Then your options are either to loop over the list in the `Callback` or use a `Map<Integer, ArrayList<Player>>` to map a team id to a list of players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the server returns a list [...], but the [...] object doesn't contain the  [...] id

Here are some options that I can think of (pardon my incomplete Retrofit code)

Option 1: Loop over the Retrofit result. At the cost of iterating over the list, this is good if you absolutely need the variable reference with each object.

```
final String id = "bla";

Call call = service.getData(id);
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SomeClass>>() {

   public void onResponse(List<SomeClass> list) {
       for (SomeClass c : list) {
           c.setCustomField(id);
       }
   }

   // onError() {}
}
```

Option 2: Map the field to the list. You say you have a list of players on a team, and your API call appears to get those teams by ID. This is good, for example, when getting all players for all teams and you need to quickly lookup teams by ID. Essentially, you are caching the API team lookup.

```
final Map<String, ArrayList<SomeClass>> teamMap = new HashMap<>();

final String id = "bla";

Call call = service.getData(id);
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SomeClass>>() {

   public void onResponse(List<SomeClass> list) {
       teamMap.put(id, list);
   }

   // onError() {}
}
```

Option 3: Remodel the server API to return the necessary requested field with each returned object.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, the solution is an additional layer between Api and presenter. Or put Api inside this layer which will exchange of Api

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor for your SomeClass which will not require any arguments and fill default values in it. It will be invoked by Gson and these default value will stay unless json overwrites them

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int id;
    //... some other fields
    //and constructors

    public SomeClass(){
        this.id = -1; //default value for contructor
    }
}
```

You also can take a look [custom instance creator](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator)

Comment: Sorry, but in my case the default identifier is not needed